# toggleClass() not working - probably something stupid :(

Tags: jquery, html

I am comparing the advantages of the function() parameter in `.toggleClass()` versus using selectors for the same task. I've written something very simple but it is refusing to toggle the class `.text` - does anyone see anything wrong?

HTML:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" class="check" />
<button type="submit" tabindex="1">Click me to toggle class</button>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
// check if img has class 'check' and is an even child ..
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("img:nth-child(even)[class='check']").toggleClass("text");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CF48C/1/

Comment: The answers below solve your problem. However, if sometime in the future, you need to use the attribute type selector for something like this, you could use the `[attribute~="value"]` (attribute contains) selector. There are loads of attribute selectors at your disposal. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) is a full list of them. Just for reference purposes, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/CF48C/10/) is your fiddle updated to show the attribute contains selector. That being said, the preferred method is that described in the answers below.

Comment: Hmm...Not sure. I've actually never used the `.toggleClass()` function. The advantage of using selectors though, is that jQuery will take care of the heavy lifting for you. I would imagine, the selectors would be faster simply because most of the time, jQuery is using the native `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()` function internally when available. Native functions will always run faster than custom ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you added the `text` class, `[class='check']` won't match your element, because the class is actually `check text`. Try the class selector instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/2P2A3/

```
$("img.check:nth-child(even)")
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but i have another question (if you feel like answering). How does one know when to use the traversal methods/function parameters on other methods vs selectors? It seems like there is very little only one solution can accomplish.

Comment: Generally, you use traversal methods when you want to select an element _relative_ to some other element.

Comment: For example, should I filter the odd elements (with class "check") with the function parameter of `.toggleClass()` or am I better off with selectors like in my question?

Comment: Ah, I generally use the function parameter of a jquery method when I want to do something different based on something specific about each element. But I would still filter the list beforehand with a selector so I'm only calling the function for elements that should be acted on. So in your case, I think you have it right. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 2):

try this jquery:

```
// check if img has class 'check' and is an even child ..
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("img.check:nth-child(even)").toggleClass("text");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/kqZLP/)

You need [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$("img.check:nth-child(even)").toggleClass("text");
```

---

Problem

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

`[class='check']` matches element who have only class `check`.

But when you add class `text` to clas becomes `check text`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be almost correct.

```
$(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("img.check:nth-child(even)").toggleClass("text");
  });
});
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L3S9u/ It's working fine for me.

SORRY, Forgot to paste the correct code.

Comment: It will work the first time only. Afterward, the `class` attribute contains `class="check text"` which will never match...

Comment: 1) It doesn't work, because it never removes the class. 2) "Your code works" should be a comment, not an answer.